# What is the Concurrency Control technique used in Meteor

Tags: meteor, real-time, collaboration, optimistic-concurrency, operational-transform

I am pretty new to Meteor, But I found it interesting.

I am just wondering what is the underlying technique or algorithm that Meteor uses to do concurrency control in Real-time and how it works with conflicts? is it based on Operational Transformation (OT) or something else? Also, it would be helpful to know the architecture of Meteor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no conflict resolution in Meteor. MongoDB controls atomic operations, but the last write wins. You can try to do things a little more carefully by using `upsert` operations, etc.

There is currently no native OT support for Meteor, but it is [on the roadmap](https://trello.com/c/tkBErvIk/39-operational-transformation) and in the meantime people like me have made packages that allow OT packages like sharejs to be integrated into Meteor apps: https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs.